# Incrontab not processing IF statement

Tags: regex, linux, shell

First off I'm a Windows guy but getting tasked with Linux now.  I am using `incrontab` to watch a directory on an Oracle Linux server.

I am trying to modify it so that if it sees file `F078311` it will echo Test to the log file.  Otherwise it will check to see if the file matches the 2nd format and executes that echo.

It is running the 2nd IF and echo'ing the date to the log but is not echoing the Test to the log.  Is there something wrong with my syntax?

It is watching the `/export` directory. and `$1` would be `/export/F073811`

```
incrontab -l
/export IN_MODIFY,IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_MOVED_TO /usr/local/scripts/EXPrename.sh $@/$#
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This file is invoked using incron and will rename the file with the current date.

# Set newdate as current date, YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS
newdate="$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"

#Sets the filename as the filename_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS
filename="A$newdate.txt"

joblog="/logs/joblog.log"


[[ ( $1 =~ F073811$ ) ]] &&  echo Test >> /logs/joblog.log

#checks to file format to see if it looks like name_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.  If it does not then it renames the file to that format.
[[ ! ( $1 =~ A[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6}\.txt$ ) ]] && echo ---- `date` ------ >> "$joblog"
```

Comment: can you print `$1` ?

Comment: `/export/F073811`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, no need for regex, use `basename` to compute exact filename without path, then just check for equality

```
[[ $(basename $1) = F073811 ]] &&  echo Test >> /logs/joblog.log
```

Note: I just noticed that your command line works for me as-is, but not in Bash 3, only in Bash 4. The above method works for both and doesn't involve regexes, plus it won't match `/export/XXXXF073811` whereas your regex would.

The more I think of it the more I'm positive that the problem could very well be that you're called with `/export/F073811\r` as first argument (MS-DOS line termination char slipped in, very frequent on Linux)

Comment: I was actually on track to use the basename idea but got distracted and went off on another tangent.  The file name won't ever change and will always be F078311 so this worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Good, but there's still a mystery about regexes since it should work. Are you using bash 3? and are you sure your 2nd regex works (if first one doesn't work, why the 2nd one would ?) the condition is negative so if it fails it will execute the echo in the log every time.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: The 2nd regex works in that it basically loops through the file names.  If the filename doesn't match `AYYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.txt` then it echo's the date to the log file and renames the files to `AYYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.txt`.  I truncated that part as it wasn't relevant to the required solution.

Comment: ok, can you test this: `[[ sed-4.2.2.tar.bz2 =~ tar.bz2$ ]] && echo matched` and tell me if it prints "`matched`" ? (from console and your cron task)? I really don't like mysteries like this, even if you got your problem solved.

Comment: Both print `matched` both ways.

Comment: okay, there's still the possibility of the \r char at the end of the argument, that must be removed when being passed to `basename`, but not with the regex where chars are processed "raw".